# Remove duplicate with separate column check TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables having same columns and permission records in it. 
 One columns named IsAllow is available in both tables.
 I am getting records of both tables in combine using UNION
 But want to skip similar records if IsAllow = 0 in any one column - I don't want those records. But UNION returns all records and am getting confused.

```
 Below are columns 
 IsAllow, UserId, FunctionActionId
```

> > I tried union but it gives both records. I want to exclude IsAllow = 0 in either table.

```
Sample data table 1
IsAllow UserId FunctionActionId
1         2           5
1         2           8

Sample data table 2
IsAllow UserId FunctionActionId
0         2           5 (should be excluded)
1         2           15
```

Comment: I'm confused, too.  Could I buy either a vowel or some sample input and output data?  And the query you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() 
                       over(partition by UserId, FunctionActionId order by IsAllow desc) rn 
            from 
             (select * from table1
              union all
              select * from table2) t)
select * from cte where rn = 1 and IsAllow = 1
```

Version2:

```
select distinct coalesce(t1.UserId, t2.UserId) as UserId, 
                coalesce(t1.FunctionActionId, t2.FunctionActionId) as FunctionActionId,
                1 as IsAllow
from tabl1 t1
full join table2 t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId and 
                       t1.FunctionActionId  = t2.FunctionActionId 
where (t1.IsAllow = 1 and t2.IsAllow = 1) or
      (t1.IsAllow = 1 and t2.IsAllow is null) or
      (t1.IsAllow is null and t2.IsAllow = 1)
```

Comment: If there are 2 rows comes similar in both table1 and table2. and if in any table.. for that row isAllow = 0 then that record should be avoided. it should not listed.

Comment: Thank you - It works, I tried with 2 CTEs and then not exists in one of them also gives results..